# sharepoint API rest custom column http 400

Tags: column, api, http-400-bad-request

I have a list in sharepoint, where I have put the totals of the columns I am interested in.

ID
Count=50

Certification
Count=9

I want to display these counts on another page. I have found a code to do it for the ID column, but it doesn't work when I try to adapt it for the Custom column I created called Certification.

_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Community Map')/items => this works fine and is giving me back 50 items

_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Community Map')/items?$select=ID => this works fine and is giving me back 50 items

_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Community Map')/items?$select=Certification => this doesn't work and I get HTTP 400 The webpage cannot be found.

Could you please let me know what's wrong in my url?

Thanks and regards,

Maud

Comment: Do you get this error on hitting the url in browser or in your ajax / http call? Also check the internal name of your custom column.

Answer (score 0):

Your Url seems fine.
Mention the type of Certification Column(Single line of text or something else?).

Also Just check your url is in following format or not:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List Name')/items?$select=CustomColumnName
```

Where "List Name"  =>  Display name of your list and

"CustomColumnName" =>  Internal name of your custom column

You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

@  harshal gite: It is both that don't work: the URL in browser and in the code. The browser is giving me HTTP400 and the code is giving me back an error.

@ Ganesh Sanap: The column type is single line of text. I don't think it is the list name as it is working fine when I put select=ID

I have this problem no matter which custom column I pick. What is the internal column name and how can I see it?

I use the column name that I have defined in my list settings. Is there another one?

Thanks,
Maud

Comment: Hi Maud - welcome to SP SE.  I think your Answer would be better posted as a comment instead - try out using 'add a comment' instead.

Comment: Hello, I tried put it says I need 50 points to comment.